# DmC white screen after gaining devil trigger

Tags: pc, dmc-devil-may-cry

I'm playing the PC version of DmC: Devil May Cry.
Whenever I get to the dreamworld-ish place and get the Devil Trigger ability, I:

1. Defeat the 3 chainsaw-wielding enemies, but not in a single devil trigger
2. Get a reddish glow around Dante before he gets warped back to reality
3. See a white screen, but the controls still work fine, and I can hear the sound of walking and weapons when using the appropriate controls
4. I obviously can't progress like that, so I restart from a checkpoint. This puts me back at the start of that dreamworld, but the controls will now not respond to anything except camera movement with the right analog stick - not even bringing up the menu will work.

I've also noticed a patch of Dante's hair at the back right has become white, whatever level I load now. I have the Devil Trigger ability in any level, as well.

So I've tried:

- Loading from the latest checkpoint - this just ends up freezing me
- Retrying the level - doesn't change anything
- Verifying the game files in Steam - doesn't need to redownload anything
- Not using Devil Trigger on the 3 chainsaw-dudes

Nothing's come close to working, and I know the opening of that level all too well now. I really don't want to lose my savegame, which is the only advice I've come across. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow. The problem was launching the game with `-nomoviestartup` under the launch options in Steam. Without that, it works fine.

The `-nomoviestartup` launch option is used to skip the intro videos when starting up the game. I guess it skips too much videos.

Credit goes to [Ahi](http://steamcommunity.com/app/220440/discussions/0/846945411144191465/#c846945579811035417).